# Aggregate data in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a natural way in a `numpy` array, to aggregate rows that have same 1st column value? i.e. such that:

```
A = numpy.array([[1, 2], [1, 7], [2, 14], [3, -1], [3, 6]])

#[[ 1  2]
# [ 1  7]
# [ 2 14]
# [ 3 -1]
# [ 3  6]]
```

would give

```
[[ 1  9]
 [ 2 14]
 [ 3  5]
```

Comment: No @AshwiniChaudhary, this is a pandas solution, that I currently don't it (I only use numpy for this project).

Comment: Did you check the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041823/846892?