# Indexing back to the one from the many

Tags: python, numpy, blender

*Some preamble:*

[image]

In a recent answer on blender stackexchange selected UV verts based on their coordinates.

The image shows a simple mesh with 9 vertices and 4 faces. A meshes "loops" is the verts in each face. So for this mesh it has 16 loops. A UV is associated with a loop.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
uv_layer = me.uv_layers.active
# get uv values
uvs = np.empty((2 * len(me.loops), 1))
uv_layer.data.foreach_get("uv", uvs)
# select 
u, v = uvs.reshape((-1, 2)).T
uv_layer.data.foreach_set(
        "select",
         np.logical_and(
            (u >= 0) & (u <= 1),
            (v >= 0) & (v <= 1)
            )
        )
```

*End preamble*

For example sake, the selected uv coords. (in loop order)

```
>>> uvlayer.data.foreach_get("select", uvselect)
>>> uvselect
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

The vertex index associated with the loop. The middle vertex above is in 4 times (once for each face), there will be 4 with 2 entries and the four outer corners with 1. (again in loop order)

```
>>> me.loops.foreach_get("vertex_index", loop_vert_index)
>>> loop_vert_index
array([8, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 7, 2, 0, 5, 8, 4, 5, 1, 6, 8], dtype=int32)
```

The current selection of the 9 vertices.

```
>>> me.vertices.foreach_get("select", vert_select)
>>> vert_select
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

The question:  how can I take the uv selection `uvselect`, mapped  with the `loop_vert_index` to create the `vert_select` if any of the loops associated with a vert is selected?.  *eg*  middle vert (index 8)  selected if any of loops 0, 5, 10 or 15 are selected), in a "numpy" way.

EDIT.

Have found a way using the method outlined in [Sum rows where value equal in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041286/sum-rows-where-value-equal-in-column) to get, via [approach 2 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30041823/5317130) if for example all loops were selected

```
vert_select = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 4]
```

which can be used to select the mesh vertices. (Equiv of select vert if  `any` loop is selected).

Comment: Please do not edit the question to include the answer; post an answer instead (and then accept it, so that it can be useful for others in the future).

Comment: Cheers for the prod. The question edit was in more a step towards answer.  Often finding myself prodding same on BSE, least I didn't put SOLVED in the title lol.  In as much as I've answered, such a novice wrt  numpy that always feel there is a "better approach".

Answer (score 0):

**`Numpy.logical_or.at`**

Putting forward as an answer method outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30042202/5317130 however `unique` was not required in this case.

`logical_or.at` will set True for  any vert that has at least one of its loops selected.  Similarly with `add.at`  Use of `logical_and.at` will require all loops selected for vert selection.

```
import numpy as np
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data

uvlayer = me.uv_layers.active
A = np.empty((2, len(me.loops)), dtype=np.int32)
me.loops.foreach_get("vertex_index", A[0])
uvlayer.data.foreach_get("select", A[1])

vert_sel = np.zeros(len(me.vertices), dtype=np.int32)

np.logical_or.at(vert_sel, *A)
print(vert_sel.T)
me.vertices.foreach_set("select", vert_sel)
```